# Handling Null Values in Controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having issues and dont exaclty know what to do.  Have a mvc project and in my controller created my linq query to access my data.  But I've update some of the data and there are 0 or values.  How do I handle that in my linq query?  In particular the d.direct has some 0 values.  I've tried handling in the stored procedure using a case when statement but that didnt work when the page was displayed

here is the error message:

> ```
> Line 2005:                get {
> Line 2006:                    try {
> Line 2007:                        return ((double)(this[this.tableFactSpendingByIndustry.EmplDirectColumn]));
> Line 2008:                    }
> Line 2009:                    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e)
> ```

```
var rows = from d in dt
           select new object[] {
               string.Empty,//+
               d.industry_code.ToString(), 
               d.industry_desc,//description                                                
               string.Format("{0:C1}",DoD/cScale),//spending millions                                                    
               string.Format("{0:N0}",d.Direct),//direct
               string.Format("{0:N0}",d.Indirect),//indirect
               string.Format("{0:N0}",d.Induced),//induced
               string.Format("{0:C0}", Math.Round(Wage,0)),//avg ann wage
               d.nextLevelMin.ToString(),
               d.nextLevelMax.ToString(),                                                                 
           };//end select statement

           return Json(new
           {                  
               iTotalRecords = dt.Count(),
               aaData = rows
           },  //end json return statement
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting errors? Is something getting displayed (or not displayed) that you would not expect?

Comment: this is the error in the conosle: 
 
Line 2005:                get {
Line 2006:                    try {
Line 2007:                        return ((double)(this[this.tableFactSpendingByIndustry.EmplDirectColumn]));
Line 2008:                    }
Line 2009:                    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {

Comment: Other wise the data table that uses that query will not populate

Comment: Could you please add the error message into the question itself. It seems it got cut off in the comment.

Comment: I put the error message on top of the code in

Comment: This code (on Line 2007, etc) is it a code you've written or is it framework generated?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
d.nextLevelMin != null ? d.nextLevelMin.ToString() : string.empty
```